# TFS with OctoDeploy: deployment Octopus Exited with code - -1

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

I have intermittent build failure in TFS

How do you solve **Octopus Exited with code - 1**

```
Exception Message: Octopus Exited with code - -1 (type Exception)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Comment: When in the build is this happening?  Is it trying to push packages to a nuget repository? Is this during an automated deployment as part of the build?

Comment: Does Octopus fail (Red in the octopus dashboard) or the failure that TFS cannot communicate with Octopus?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**WorkAround**

Only work around is to monitor the build and trigger deploy again and the issue will go away.

So far I have no other solution

**Common answer I have found**

Thanks for getting in touch! Very rarely we get ghost processes.
To reset them on your tentacle please do the following:

```
> cd \Program Files\Octopus Deploy\Tentacle
> 
> tentacle.exe service --stop tentacle.exe reset-activities tentacle.exe
> service --start
```

That is however not very neat solution and does not remove the cause as far I can tell.